# Unsigned int não funciona?

Tags: c, c++

Seguinte, meu programa continua compilando mesmo depois de eu ter atribuido um valor negativo à uma variável unsigned, por que isso acontece? Uso a IDE Code::Blocks 13.12

```
unsigned int numero1 = -1;
```

Comment: O que acontece?

Comment: O programa roda normal. Caso eu de um printf("%i", numero1); me mostra -1.

Answer (score 6):

A atribuição converte `-1`, que é um *int*, para *unsigned int*.
A regra de conversão de *signed-to-unsigned* é `(INT_MAX + 1) - intValue`, neste caso como `intValue` é `-1` o resultado é `INT_MAX`

Se você usar `printf("%i", numero1)` será apresentado `-1`.
Para apresentar o valor correto use `printf("%u", numero1)`

Fonte: [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7152759/2556111)

Comment: com printf("%u", numero1"); é exibido 4294967291, porém, se eu tirar o unsigned ele continua exibindo esse número...

Comment: Sim, isso é o esperado, porque `%u` converte `numero1` para *unsigned*, assim como, quando usou `%i`, ele foi convertido para *int*.

Comment: Então o unsigned é inútil?

Comment: É útil se você necessitar de toda a sua amplitude de valor positivo (0 a 4,294,967,295 em vez de –2,147,483,648 a 2,147,483,647) ou quando usado em operações *bitwise*.

Answer (score 3):

Duas coisas estão ocorrendo:

- primeiro conversões implícitas entre int e unsigned int (se você ativar todas as warnings do compilador, é provável que ele avise que o código está meio "estranho");
- segundo, como a função printf aceita qualquer tipo, você precisa especificar manualmente como deseja exibir o valor, com %d (que é igual a %i no printf, mas não no scanf) ou %u (novamente, se ativar todas as warnings do compilador pode ser que ele avise sobre a incongruência entre a declaração e o printf, dependendo da versão do compilador)

O unsigned é inútil? Bem, ele tem seu propósito, mas é verdade que para verificação de erros ele não serve mesmo!

Por exemplo, se você fizer

```
unsigned int numero1 = 1 - 2; // Dá -1, mas vai ser convertido para unsigned
if(numero1 < 0){ // nunca será true
    // ...
}
```

você terá um belo e inútil if que nunca executará porque a condição é sempre falsa (o resultado da operação está sendo interpretado como um número positivo bem grande), mas se tirar o unsigned o if vai funcionar (o mesmo padrão de bits dentro do computador será interpretado como -1).

Answer (score -1):

Provavelmente o compilador está removendo o sinal e atribuindo somente o valor `1`a variável, faça um `printf` desta variável para fazer o teste. quando se realiza o print com `%u` será desconsiderado o bit que representa que o valor é negativo/positivo e irá considera-lo parte do digito logo irá gerar um numero gigantesco `4294967291` quando se realiza o print com ´%i` irá considerar o ultimo digito como o representante do tipo do numero (negativo/positivo).

Comment: O programa roda normal. Caso eu de um printf("%i", numero1); me mostra -1

Comment: você deve utilizar `%u`.

Comment: com printf("%u", numero1"); é exibido 4294967291, porém, se eu tirar o unsigned ele continua exibindo esse número..

Comment: O compilador não "remove o sinal" literalmente, mas gera código que interpreta o bit como magnitude em vez de sinal (você também disse isso, mas ficou um pouco confuso). Isso afeta comparações, multiplicações, etc.

Além disso, por características da linguagem C, o printf precisa ser informado **de novo** sobre o tipo da variável, então é esse tipo que acaba prevalecendo (mas você sempre deve passar o tipo certo, porque nem todos os tipos têm o mesmo tamanho).